# PHP mail returns TRUE, but e-mail is not sent

Tags: php

Simple code:

`mail("my_email@gmail.com", $subject, $text);`

It doesn't send email, but it still, returns TRUE. What is hapenning?

P.S. Even if I add headers, the result is the same!

Comment: care for providing some information about your server? is it linux oder windows? what server are you sending through? are you able to send an email using a mail client via that server you are sending your mails from php?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

from the [man page for mail()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php):

> Returns TRUE if the mail was
>   successfully accepted for delivery,
>   FALSE otherwise.
>
> It is important to note that just
>   because the mail was accepted for
>   delivery, it does **NOT** mean the mail
>   will actually reach the intended
>   destination.

---

Basically there is nothing you *really* can do in plain ol' PHP unless you ***actually*** check the wire to see what is going on. I would suggest using some mail library that has some indication of whether the mail sent or not (if it exists)

Answer (score 3):

Do you know for a fact the email is not sending?  The email could go from your php script to your SMTP server, but get dropped somewhere between the first SMTP server and gmail.

Try looking at network traffic to verify that the email is being sent using something similar to [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org).

Answer (score 2):

See @Neal's comment.  Simply returning `true` means very little.

You should check your PHP.ini and make sure your SMTP servers are set correctly (if on Windows) or that your sendmail path (Linux) is correct.  From there, check your sendmail configuration.